# Best Linear Over-Estimator of Shifted Step-Function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider shifted step function:
\begin{equation}
f(x,\theta)=\begin{cases} 0 & x < \theta \\ 1 & x \geq \theta\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ is a parameter that determines the jump point. The goal is to find the "best" linear over-estimator of $f$. More precisely, for the line $ax+b$, we seek:
\begin{equation}
(a^*,b^*) = \arg\min_{a,b} \int_0^1 (ax+b-f(x))^2 dx \mbox{ s.t. } \forall x \in [0,1] ; ax+b \geq f(x)
\end{equation}

Alternatively, we could use $\sup$ instead of $\ell_2$,
\begin{equation}
(a^*,b^*) = \arg\min_{a,b} \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |ax+b-f(x)| \mbox{ s.t. } \forall x \in [0,1] ; ax+b \geq f(x)
\end{equation}

I am wondering if $(a^*,b^*)$ can be expressed in closed form as a function of $\theta$, for either $\ell_2$ or $\sup$ norms (ideally for both)?

Your help would be appreciated!

Golabi

Comment: The answer *is* going to depend on the error function.

Comment: Also, do you require $ax+b\geq f(x)$ for _all_ $x$, or just for $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Actually, you _can't_ require $ax+b\geq f(x)$ for all $x$, otherwise, the only right answer is $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if was not clear. There is a constraint on $x$ at the right side of the objective function that states the upper bound needs to be valid only on $x \in [0,1]$. Also, as you said, the answer depends on the error function. I would be happy to know the answer for either $\ell_2$ or $\sup$ norm, or ideally both of them.